# installation of unity-webapps-preview 12.04 not possible

Tags: 12.04, webapps

I tried to install `unity-webapps-preview` on  the long term support version of ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

I used [this HOWTO](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/install-new-ubuntu-webapps-technology.html)

But every time I try, this happens:

```
tom@Tom-Laptop:~/Downloads$ sudo apt-get install  unity-webapps-preview 
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen... Fertig
Einige Pakete konnten nicht installiert werden. Das kann bedeuten, dass
Sie eine unmögliche Situation angefordert haben oder, wenn Sie die
Unstable-Distribution verwenden, dass einige erforderliche Pakete noch
nicht erstellt wurden oder Incoming noch nicht verlassen haben.
Die folgenden Informationen helfen Ihnen vielleicht, die Situation zu lösen:

Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 unity-webapps-preview : Hängt ab von: xul-ext-unity soll aber nicht installiert werden
                         Hängt ab von: xul-ext-websites-integration soll aber nicht installiert werden
                         Hängt ab von: xul-ext-webaccounts soll aber nicht installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Translation:

```
tom @ tom-laptop: ~ / Downloads $ sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-preview
Reading package lists ... ready
Dependency tree
Status information is read ... ready
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that
You have requested an impossible situation or if you are
Unstable distribution use that some required packages have
not have been created or have have not been moved from incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
unity-webapps-preview: Depends: xul-ext-unity will not be installed
Depends on: xul-ext-websites-integration will not be installed
Depends on: xul-ext-web accounts will not be installed
E: Problems can not be corrected, you have held broken packages back.
```

and when i try to install those needed packages (`xul-ext-unity`, `xul ext websites integration`, `xule xt webaccounts`)  I get this:

```
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 xul-ext-unity : Beschädigt: firefox (>= 15.+) aber 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 soll installiert werden
 xul-ext-webaccounts : Beschädigt: firefox (>= 14.+) aber 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 soll installiert werden
 xul-ext-websites-integration : Beschädigt: firefox (>= 15.+) aber 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 soll installiert werden
E: Probleme können nicht korrigiert werden, Sie haben zurückgehaltene defekte Pakete.
```

Translation:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  xul-ext-unity: Damaged: firefox (> = 15 +) but 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 will be installed
  xul-ext-web accounts: Damaged: firefox (> = 14 +) but 17.0 will 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 be installed
  xul-ext-websites-integration: Damaged: firefox (> = 15 +) but 17.0~b2+build1-0ubuntu0.12.04.1~mfn2 will be installed
 E: Problems can not be corrected, you have held broken packages back.
```

(Firefox 17 is installed, though)

**EDIT:**
Thanks for that extremely quick answer, but unfortunately it helped nothing. Same error still.

PS: I even tried `sudo apt-get install -f -m unity-webapps-preview`

Comment: You can use `LANG=en_US command` to force `command` to use English strings.

Answer (score -1):

Open up your terminal and do this :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

among those 1 is for updating cache and 2 is for fixing broken packages and 3 is to deal with held packages .

hope that helps .

thank you .

Comment: what does the -f mean?

Comment: Fix install to fix broken packages